# How do I extract table metadata from a database using python

Tags: python, mysql, database, postgresql, metadata

I want to come up minimal set of queries/loc that extracts the `table metadata` within a `database`, on as many versions of database as possible. I'm using `PostgreSQl`. I'm trying to get this using `python`. But I've no clue on how to do this, as I'm a python newbie.

I appreciate your ideas/suggestions on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask your database driver, in this case `psycopg2`, to return some metadata about a database connection you've established. You can also ask the database directly about some of it's capabilities, or schemas, but this is highly dependent on the version of the database you're connecting to, as well as the type of database.

Here's an example taken from http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/438133-find-out-schema-psycopg for `PostgreSQL`:

```
>>> import psycopg2 as db
>>> conn = db.connect('dbname=billings user=steve password=xxxxx port=5432')
>>> curs = conn.cursor()
>>> curs.execute("""select table_name from information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_type='BASETABLE'""")
>>> curs.fetchall()
[('contacts',), ('invoicing',), ('lines',), ('task',), ('products',),('project',)]
```

However, you probably would be better served using an `ORM` like `SQLAlchemy`. This will create an `engine` which you can query about the database you're connected to, as well as normalize how you connect to varying database types.

If you need help with `SQLAlchemy`, post another question here! There's TONS of information already available by searching the site.

Comment: what if I the db is hive or teradata??

Comment: @Giri: Sure. PyHive (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyHive/0.1.0) is an interface between SQLAlchemy and Hive. Teradata is ODBC driven, and doesn't really fit in as well, so i'd say no on that one. YMMV though. SQLA is more geared towards traditional databases like MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite.